# D3 pan+ zoom constraints

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to zoomable/draggle rectangle from going outside of the svg bounds when panning and zooming. I've tried to  implement it based off of this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520), but i cant seem to get it to work. I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3wxP/) with just the rectangle that is zoomable and draggable. Again, im trying to make it so that you can not drag the rectangle outside of the svg box i put the border on. I know i need to update the move function. the code below is from the first link example but it does not seem to work well so i commented part of it out.

```
function move() {
  var t = d3.event.translate,
  s = d3.event.scale;

  //t[0] = Math.min(width / 2 * (s - 1), Math.max(width / 2 * (1 - s), t[0]));
  //t[1] = Math.min(height / 2 * (s - 1) + 230 * s, Math.max(height / 2 * (1 - s) - 230 * s, t[1]));
  //zoom.translate(t);
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Edit: So additionally i need to be able to drag the rectangle when you are zoomed in all the way and its bigger than the svg. In the image below, the blue rectangle is the svg and green would be the rectangle and you are zoomed in all the way so that the green rectangle takes up the much more than the SVG. This is similar to the map in the [constrained zoom example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520). You can zoom into the states and drag across the country, navigating to states outside the current svg size

[image: example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by constraining the translation coordinates you set to the size of the box:

```
var t = d3.event.translate,
    s = d3.event.scale;

t[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(t[0], width - s*50));
t[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(t[1], height - s*50));

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
```

This is constraining the x coordinate to be between 0 and the width minus however much space is required to show the box completely -- this depends on the zoom level and the term therefore contains `s`. For the y coordinate, it is exactly the same.

This is much easier if you don't use both a translation and explicit coordinate settings through `x` and `y` for the box -- to offset from the top left corner, simply set an initial translation.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3wxP/1/).

Comment: Actually, one additional question. I also need to be able to drag the rectangle to navigate to each corner that is off the page when zoomed in. Using a rectangle without any fill makes it easier to see (see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamescharlesworth/d3wxP/3/). In the example, if you are zoomed in all the way, you can not drag the rectangle to get to the corner that is off the page.  Ideally, i would like to stop the drag once the end of the rectangle is brought onto the page.

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- how would you drag the rectangle to something that isn't visible?

Comment: Update the question, with additional info. Thanks

Comment: For that you would just need to remove the `s*` from the computation of the max values, i.e. `width - 50` instead `width - s*50`.

Comment: That helped and got me to what i was trying to do (updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamescharlesworth/d3wxP/5/)). I apologize for not explaining it better from the start. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi! I just asked a question that is a tad similar. I tried using your approach but it is still not that good, because i have different constraints. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156576/d3-js-limit-panning-in-force-layout I would be grateful if you can help me out.