# How to find current X and Y value of an element ? HTML, JS, D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I wish to use the drag capability in D3 to drag some circles around the screen. But what I don't want to happen is for the user to drag the circles outside the window.

So what I need is a 'boundary' so the circles can not be dragged off screen.

Here is my drag function.

```
function drag(xLower,xHigher,yLower,yHigher){
    clog("drag");
    return d3.behavior.drag()
             .origin(function() {
                var g = this;
                return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                        y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
            })
            .on("drag", function(d) {

                g = this;
                translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;

                x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];

                if(x<xLower){x=xLower;}
                if(x>xHigher){x=xHigher;}
                if(y<yLower){y=yLower;}
                if(y>yHigher){y=yHigher;}

                d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();             
            });
}
```

This takes in 4 parameters giving me a boundary relative to its current position but I am unsure how to apply something like this to all circles :

```
if(x < 0) {x = 0}
if(x > screenWidth) {x = screenWidth}
```

and same for `'y'`.

I want to find the `X` value on a global scale, i.e what the `X` value really is so I can apply the if statements above.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991210/d3-pan-zoom-constraints

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that only applys to the shapes current co-ordinates. ie: the x and y value are set to 0 once i start the drag. I wish to use the global x and y value

Comment: That would be `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y`. It should be easier to determine whether you're within your bounding box with relative coordinates though.

Comment: i logged d3.event.x and it isnt relative to the global co-ordinates. For example, the circle starts off at [500,0], i move it to the right 50px and i would think when logging d3.event.x it should say [550,0], when it only says [50,0]. I want it working on the global coordinate system, how do i do this ?