# Stacked bar chart with smaller bar value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my below code snippet i tried to make my smaller bar visible using log scale but this cause upper bars to render small. I'm novice to D3, really struggling to make it work. i want to make my bar visible so that labels will be visible inside bar area, now it's over lapping with other smaller bar labels.

```js
var data = [{"month":"JAN","Insolvency":"1","Operating Company":"1","SPV / Asset Backed":"0","Operational Company":"0","TBD":"0"},{"month":"FEB","Insolvency":"1","Operating Company":"11","SPV / Asset Backed":"9","TBD":"1","Operational Company":"0"},{"month":"MAR","Insolvency":"3","Operating Company":"44","SPV / Asset Backed":"33","TBD":"8","Operational Company":"0"},{"month":"APR","Insolvency":"3","Operating Company":"27","SPV / Asset Backed":"31","TBD":"3","Operational Company":"0"},{"month":"MAY","Operating Company":"2","SPV / Asset Backed":"5","TBD":"1","Operational Company":"0","Insolvency":"0"},{"month":"JUL","Insolvency":"44","Operating Company":"9","TBD":"1","SPV / Asset Backed":"0","Operational Company":"0"},{"month":"AUG","Operating Company":"24","SPV / Asset Backed":"30","TBD":"2","Operational Company":"0","Insolvency":"0"},{"month":"SEP","Insolvency":"189","Operating Company":"74","SPV / Asset Backed":"20","Operational Company":"0","TBD":"0"},{"month":"OCT","Insolvency":"3","Operating Company":"16","SPV / Asset Backed":"54","Operational Company":"0","TBD":"0"},{"month":"NOV","Insolvency":"1","Operating Company":"3","SPV / Asset Backed":"25","TBD":"3","Operational Company":"0"},{"month":"DEC","Insolvency":"6","Operating Company":"0","SPV / Asset Backed":"0","Operational Company":"0","TBD":"0"}];
     
let xData = d3.keys(data[0]);
const yData = xData.shift();
var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

var margin = {
 top : 40,
 right : 50,
 bottom : 30,
 left : 50
}, width = 500, height = 300, padding = 100;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([ 0, width ], .05);

var y = d3.scale.log().range([ height, 0.5 ]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(0, ".1s")
  .innerTickSize(-width).tickPadding(10);

var svg = d3
  .select("#ashu")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
 return data.map(function(d, yData) {
  return {
   x : d[Object.keys(d)[0]],
   y : +d[c]
  };
 });
});

var totals = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
 return d.health;
}).rollup(function(d) {
 return d3.sum(d, function(g) {

  return d3.sum(d3.values(g));
 });
}).entries(data);


var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
 return d.x;
}));
var total = 0;
var maximumY = d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
  function(d) {
   return (d.y + d.y0);
  });
y.domain([ 0.5, maximumY ]).base(2).nice().clamp(true);

var layer1 = svg.selectAll(".stack1").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
  .append("g").attr("class", "stack1").style("fill",
    function(d, i) {
     return color(i);
    }).attr("transform",
      "translate(5,0)");

layer1.selectAll("rect").data(function(d) {
 return d;
}).enter().append("rect").attr("x", function(d) {
 return x(d.x);
}).attr("y", function(d) {
 return y(d.y + d.y0);
}).attr("height", function(d) {
 return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
}).attr("width", x.rangeBand()-2);

layer1.selectAll("text").data(totals).enter().append("text").text(
  function(d) {
   return d.values;
  }).attr("x", function(d, i) {
 return x(d.key) + (x.rangeBand()) / 2;
}).attr("y", function(d) {
 return y(d.values + 10);
}).attr("dy", "0.35em").attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill",
  "#1a8cff");


var layer2 = svg.selectAll(".stack2").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
  .append("g").attr("class", "stack2").style("fill", "black");

layer2.selectAll(".shadow").data(function(d) {
 return d;
}).enter().append("text")
.attr("class", "shadow")
.text(function(d) {
 return (d.y === 0 ? '':d.y);
}).attr("x", function(d, i) {
 return x(d.x) + (x.rangeBand()) / 2;
}).attr("y", function(d) {
 return y(d.y0 + (d.y / 2));
}).attr("dy", "0.35em").attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill",
  "black");


svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
  "translate(0," + (height + 5) + ")").call(xAxis);

svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
  "translate(15px,0)").call(y_axis);

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend").data(color.domain().slice())
  .enter().append("g").attr("class", "legend").attr(
    "transform",
    function(d, i) {
     return "translate(0," + Math.abs((i - 8) * 20)
       + ")";
    });

legend.append("rect").attr("x", width + 10).attr("width", 18).attr(
  "height", 18).style("fill", color);

legend.append("text").attr("class", "legendText").attr("x",
  width + 32).attr("y", 10).attr("dy", ".35em").style(
  "text-anchor", "start").text(function(d, i) {
 return xData[i];
});
```

```css
.textRect {
 fill: grey;
 stroke: none;
}

text {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
}

path {
 color: green;
}

div.tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 7px;
 font: 12px sans-serif;
 background: #333333;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 pointer-events: none;
 color: white;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: grey;
 stroke-width: 1;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
 stroke: lightgrey;
 stroke-opacity: 0.7;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
 stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="ashu" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change the data position" and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I do not understand why people new to D3 use d3v3. It is about 2 years old and we have d3v4 and d3v5 (a lot of (good) API changes).

Comment: @rioV8 Kindly enlighten me how to do same in D3V4. I started with D3V3 coz most of the stacked graph examples online used V3 but I'm not limited to it. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#stacks (docs) and https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 for an example (v4 and v5 API are very similar)

Comment: @rioV8 can we change bar size wrt to y-axs so that smaller bars has visible size.

Comment: Use a logarithmic y-axis. Y domain can't start at 0, use some small number.

Comment: @rioV8 i've changed my code above and added d3.scale.log() now bars disappear.

Comment: @Kumar I have added an answer with a logarithmic Y-axis. It uses D3v5. Never to late to use a new version of D3. And it is hard to get the docs for D3v3, you have to browse github for a particular commit.

Comment: To make your code readable put all the code for the one-line functions on **1** line. You will want to be able to read it in 6-months time when you need to adjust it a bit. Or let somebody else be able to read it if that is the goal.

Comment: sorry i think this's coz of eclipse formatter. @rioV8

Comment: If this is the cause it will be a very good idea to disable the code formatter for this type of code. I never use a code formatter because they usually corrupt readable code and they prefer loads of useless whitespace.

Comment: @rioV8 I've used log scale but user wants normal scale and as novice in D3 I'm really struggling to make those bar bigger in size to make it visible.

Comment: @AshishKumar: The idea of a graph is to show the value of things in relation to the value of other things. If the shown representation is too small to contain text you can work with tooltips when you hover the mouse over it. It it is really small compared to another value you want to know. It would give false information to draw the small thing 10x bigger.

Comment: @rioV8 but tooltips will be non-printable :(

Comment: @AshishKumar: Just before your comment I modified the solution to add a zoom functionality and tooltips. But if you want to be able to print the bar graph you have to come up with a function/graph that determines the relation of bar value to actual bar height. But using a transformation that is not uniform over the domain will lead to miss-information. **If the bar is to small to see it is very small**.

Answer (score 1):

I have converted the code to a D3v5 version.

No need to transform the data, you can work with objects.

I have no clue what you want with the `layer1` and `layer2`.
You have to add the `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

With logarithmic Y-axis. Using a 2-log is not common so I used 10-log.
But now the Insolvencies look very big.

for the JavaScript (`health` renamed to `month`)

```js
var data = [{
    "month": "JAN",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 1,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 67,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 13,
    "Bank": 15
  }, {
    "month": "FEB",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 9,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 20,
    "Bank": 5
  }, {
    "month": "MAR",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 40,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 22,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 21,
    "Bank": 99
  }, {
    "month": "APR",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 1,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 99,
    "Bank": 90
  }, {
    "month": "MAY",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 2,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 27,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 43,
    "Bank": 82
  }, {
    "month": "JUN",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 17,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 52,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 79,
    "Bank": 9
  }, {
    "month": "JUL",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 37,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 24,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 35,
    "Bank": 51
  }, {
    "month": "AUG",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 16,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 17,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 53,
    "Bank": 38
  }, {
    "month": "SEP",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 15,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 32,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 5,
    "Bank": 31
  }];
  let xKey = "month";
  let keys = d3.keys(data[0]).filter( e => e != xKey );
  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 400,
    height = 300,
    padding = 100;

  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(.05);

  var y = d3.scaleLog().range([height, 0]);
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
  var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(6); //.innerTickSize(-width).tickPadding(10);

  var svg = d3.select("#ashu")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var dataStackLayout = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);
  dataStackLayout[0].forEach(e => { e[0]=0.1; }); // do not start at 0

  x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) { return d.data[xKey]; }));
  var maximumY = d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1], function(d) { return d[1]; });
  y.domain([0.1, maximumY]).base(10).nice();

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(dataStackLayout)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data[xKey]); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(y_axis);

  var legend = g.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain().slice())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + Math.abs((i - 8) * 20) + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width + 10)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 32)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d, i) { return keys[i]; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="ashu" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
```

**Edit**

Instead of using a log-scale I have added a zoom functionality. The translation is done in the `range` and that confused me. I found the needed equation but needed a tip on where to apply the limitation on translate from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44359905/9938317.

You have to place the labels conditionally when the height of the bar is tall enough or use tooltips when you do not place a label.

Adding the tooltips was a little puzzle. I don't know a way to get the data that is attached to a parent node so I copied the key of the group over to the individual bar rects. (Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/17459746/9938317 is a solution)

```js
var data = [{
    "month": "JAN",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 1,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 67,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 13,
    "Bank": 15
  }, {
    "month": "FEB",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 9,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 20,
    "Bank": 5
  }, {
    "month": "MAR",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 40,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 22,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 21,
    "Bank": 99
  }, {
    "month": "APR",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 1,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 99,
    "Bank": 90
  }, {
    "month": "MAY",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 2,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 27,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 43,
    "Bank": 82
  }, {
    "month": "JUN",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 17,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 52,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 79,
    "Bank": 9
  }, {
    "month": "JUL",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 37,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 24,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 35,
    "Bank": 51
  }, {
    "month": "AUG",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 16,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 17,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 53,
    "Bank": 38
  }, {
    "month": "SEP",
    "INSOLVENCIES": 15,
    "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 32,
    "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 5,
    "Bank": 31
  }];
  let xKey = "month";
  let keys = d3.keys(data[0]).filter( e => e != xKey );
  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 400,
    height = 300,
    padding = 100;

  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(.05);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(6); //.innerTickSize(-width).tickPadding(10);

  var svg = d3.select("#ashu")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");
  const clipPath = svg.append('defs')
    .append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var dataStackLayout = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);
  // add the key to the bar elements
  dataStackLayout.forEach(keyElem => {
      var key = keyElem.key;
      keyElem.forEach(d => { d.key = key; });
  });

  x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) { return d.data[xKey]; }));
  var maximumY = d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1], function(d) { return d[1]; });
  y.domain([0.1, maximumY]);

  var gBars = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "bars")
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

  gBars.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataStackLayout)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data[xKey]); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .append("title").text(function(d) { return d.key; });

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  var gY = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);

  var legend = g.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain().slice())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + Math.abs((i - 8) * 20) + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width + 10)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 32)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d, i) { return keys[i]; });

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 40])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  svg.call(zoom);

  d3.select("button")
    .on("click", resetted);

  function zoomed() {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44359905/9938317
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    t.y = d3.min([t.y, 0]);
    t.y = d3.max([t.y, (1-t.k) * height]);
    var yTransform = t.rescaleY(y);
    gY.call(yAxis.scale(yTransform));
    gBars.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yTransform(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return yTransform(d[0]) - yTransform(d[1]); });
  }

  function resetted() {
    svg.transition()
       .duration(750)
       .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button>Reset</button>
<div id="ashu" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your comments and code. Same code I've tried with v3 and bars were bigger below smaller at top. 2 layers were added for rectangle and labels so that labels will overflow at bars. I'm adding clean code above.

Comment: please help me with this log thing my bars getting small at top.

Comment: That is the nature of log-scaling. You can change the lower Y-value (0.1) to say 0.5 or 1 to limit the effect. But what do you want to see? Maybe you need to define your own scaling function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your old code made some assumptions about the data format that your new data did not comply with. In the old code, the numbers were listed as strings. Also, the `health` (`month`) field was the first field in the dataset, not the second.

The following is one way to correct for these problems, but not the only way. I think it gets you moving in the right direction.

OLD ANSWER:

All I did was: 1) move `month` to the first position in each object and 2) add a `+` operator in your `dataIntermediate` function for the `y` value.

EDIT:

In light of your comment, I edited the code snippet to be tolerant of where the "month" field is.

These issues have as much to do with just JavaScript as D3. You can use any field you want for the y-axis of the graph, but you have to tell D3 what it will be.

I've updated the code snippet to set your `yData` variable to `"month"` manually. D3 doesn't make assumptions about the structure of your data, but your underlying JavaScript did with these lines:

```
let xData = d3.keys(data[0]);
const yData = xData.shift();
```

For `xData` in my code snippet, those functions cycle through your data to gather up all the keys, then filter out any repeats, and then filter out the `month`.

As for whether the each object has to have each field: it doesn't technically for the sake of D3, but at the same time D3 won't assume it is or isn't there. It all depends on how you code the chart. So, the short answer is that D3 isn't going to make assumptions about your data, and right now your code is telling D3 to attempt to draw points on the graph for data that isn't there.

If you look at your code snippet:

```
var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
  return data.map(function(d, yData) {
    return {
      x: d[Object.keys(d)[0]],
      y: +d[c]
    };
  });
});
```

You're cycling through `data` for every key listed as in your `xData` and `yData` and trying to access the `data` for it. However, for some points in your data, that key/value pair won't necessarily exist. This means you'll end up with data you pass to D3 that looks like this:

```
[
  {x: "7", y: 4, y0: 9}
  {x: "3", y: NaN, y0: 46}
  {x: "6", y: 27, y0: NaN}
  {x: "54", y: 15, y0: 168}
]
```

D3 doesn't know how to translate and plot `NaN` on a graph. I believe you could omit certain fields in your data, but you'd need to go through your code and ensure that you aren't attempting to process data that doesn't exist and pass it to D3. You also would need to go through and be sure you aren't try to access fields that aren't there in things like a tooltip.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "Operating Company" : "7",
    "month" : "March",
    "Insolvency" : "2",
    "SPV / Asset Backed" : "4",
    "Operational Company" : "0",
    "TBD": "0"
  },
  {
    "Operating Company" : "3",
    "month" : "July",
    "Insolvency" : "43",
    "TBD" : "1",
    "Operational Company" : "0",
    "SPV / Asset Backed" : "0",
  }, {
    "Operating Company" : "6",
    "month" : "August",
    "SPV / Asset Backed" : "27",
    "Operational Company" : "0",
    "Insolvency" : "0",
    "TBD": "0"
  },
  {
    "Operating Company" : "54",
    "month" : "September",
    "Insolvency" : "114",
    "Operational Company" : "1",
    "SPV / Asset Backed" : "15",
    "TBD": "0"
  }
];

let yData = "month";
const xData = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  keys = Object.keys(currentValue);
  keys.forEach(k => {
    accumulator.push(k);
  });
  return accumulator;
}, [])
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
  .filter(value => value !== "month");


    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 400,
      height = 300,
      padding = 100;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(6).innerTickSize(-width)
      .tickPadding(10);

    var svg = d3.select("#ashu").append("svg").attr("width",
      "100%").attr("height",
      "100%").append("g").attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
      return data.map(function(d, yData) {
        return {
          x: d[Object.keys(d)[0]],
          y: +d[c]
        };
      });
    });

    var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);
    
    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));
    var total = 0;
    var maximumY = d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1], function(d) {
      return (d.y + d.y0);
    });
    y.domain([0, maximumY]).nice();

    var layer1 = svg.selectAll(".stack1").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
      .append("g").attr("class", "stack").style("fill",
        function(d, i) {
          return color(i);
        });
    
    var layer2 = svg.selectAll(".stack2").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
      .append("g")
     .attr("class", "stack")
      .style("fill", "black");

    layer1.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        // this code places your hover text at the bottom of the page
        // it is not required
        // you can modify it as you see fit, and even delete it
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html("Total : " + (d.y + d.y0))
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        // this code removes the text on the bottom of the screen when
        // you move the mouse off the bar
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });
    // this code places your text labels on the bars
    // it is not required
    // you can modify it as you see fit, and even just delete it
    layer2.selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return x(d.x) + (x.rangeBand())/2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0 + (d.y/2));
      })
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "black");


    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
      "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)").call(y_axis);


    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + Math.abs((i - 8) * 20) + ")";
      });

    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width + 10)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 32)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return xData[i];
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="ashu" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: 1) Practically json don't preserve data position as you moved month in 1st position. And also i would like to learn if we can reposition the json data. 2) what if every object in json don't have all the fields can't d3 assume it not to draw. Please educate me and thanks for the reply, I thought exactly like you for data positioning and adding missing fields. 

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying comments. I've updated the code snippet and answer to hopefully be more helpful.

Comment: how to deal with these overlapping text labels on bars.

Comment: I updated the code snippet in my answer with comments pointing out where your code adds text labels to the bars, and where it adds the text to the bottom of the screen on hover. You can do whatever you want with both of these, including just removing them.