# Reposition json array object elements

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I would like to convert below json data into in different format.It's kind of rearranging my json data. I also understand that we access data by key but my requirement is something like below and I can't help it with it. Below in required data you can see month is always at 1st place.

given data :-

```
[ { "Operating Company" : "7", "month" : "March", "Insolvency" : "2", "SPV / Asset Backed" : "4" }, { "Operating Company" : "3", "month" : "July", "Insolvency" : "43", "TBD" : "1" }, { "Operating Company" : "6", "month" : "August", "SPV / Asset Backed" : "27" }, { "Operating Company" : "54", "month" : "September", "Insolvency" : "114", "Operational Company" : "1", "SPV / Asset Backed" : "15" } ]
```

Required data :-

```
[ { "month" : "March", "Operating Company" : "7", "Insolvency" : "2", "SPV / Asset Backed" : "4" }, {"month" : "July",  "Operating Company" : "3", "Insolvency" : "43", "TBD" : "1" }, { "month" : "August", "Operating Company" : "6", "SPV / Asset Backed" : "27" }, {"month" : "September",  "Operating Company" : "54", "Insolvency" : "114", "Operational Company" : "1", "SPV / Asset Backed" : "15" } ]
```

Comment: The order of object properties is not guaranteed in Javascript, and generally shouldn't matter.

Comment: Kindly help me with this.

Comment: It matters when we have to use D3.js for plotting a graph.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Following what Barmar said, what you're attempting is going to be difficult (and probably not maintainable). IMO you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suspect you'll get more help, and a better solution, if you ask a new question about how to make D3 behave the way you want

Comment: @Vlad274 I've already asked it at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367943/d3-js-change-in-json-data-position-graph-act-inappropriately/51369220#51369220) **But didn't got expected answer**

Comment: I don't use D3.js, but I'll bet anything it has a parameter that you can use to specify the order. Your problem is probably that you're allowing this to default.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON specification does not make any guarantee how a JSON processor handles the order of key-value pairs in an object:

> 6 Objects
>
> The JSON syntax does not [...] assign any significance to the ordering of name/value pairs. These are all semantic considerations that may be defined by JSON processors or in specifications defining specific uses of JSON for data interchange.
>
> Source: [*ECMA-404, 2nd Edition / December 2017, 6 Objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

ECMAScript 2015 specification does not give any guarantee about the order of keys in an Object:

> 9.1 Ordinary Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots
>   9.1.11 [[Enumerate]] ()
>
> [...] The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified [...]
>
> Source: [ECMA-262, 6th Edition / June 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate)

So you may be able to change the order of your key-value pairs in JSON Object but if you [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) that to a JavaScript Object the order is not guaranteed anymore.

However if you need to keep the order of the key-value pairs of JSON Object while parsing it in JavaScript, you need to write your own parse that is parsing JSON Object to [JavaScript Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). `Map` guarantees the order of keys.

Since you mentioned in a comment that you need this for D3.js, I'm quite sure that your actual issue is something else. Feel free to open another question for your D3.js issue.

Comment: **I've already asked the question realted to D3** [D3 asked question link in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367943/d3-js-change-in-json-data-position-graph-act-inappropriately/51369220#51369220)